# How do I GET the following JSON URL using Kendo UI?

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource

This is what the URL returns:

[image]

And this is what I'm trying to do but it returns nothing:

Kendo UI Test

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            var retrievedData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "http://...",
                        dataType: "json"
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: retrievedData,
                columns: [{
                        field: "id",
                        title: "ID",
                        width: 150
                    }, {
                        field: "NotificationType",
                        title: "NotificationType",
                        width: 150
                    }]
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

The URL is a local host and I've tried using "json" and "jsonp" as the dataType.

Am I missing anything? No data is being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue.

The issue was that I was running on IIS express. I unchecked "Use IIS Express" under the Web Tab of the configurations settings and it worked.

This is what the final code looks like now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Kendo UI Test</title>
        <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="js/kendo.web.min.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="grid"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

                var retrievedData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "http://localhost/..."
                        }
                    }
                });
                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: retrievedData,
                    columns: [{
                            field: "id",
                            title: "ID",
                            width: 150
                        }, {
                            field: "NotificationType",
                            title: "NotificationType",
                            width: 150
                        }]
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```